# How to build PHP 7.3?

Tags: server, apache2, php, compiling, git

I have a problem with building the package for PHP 7.3 from git. At the moment I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with utdatet php 7.0.x. (It's impossible to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 at my VPS, because it crashes at boot. I only have Virtuozzo to debug and I can't find the point where it crashes, so upgrading to 18.04 isn't an option yet.)

My steps so far:

I have installed all programs for build, (git, build essential, libtool, bison and re2c).

I cloned the git from GitHub with:

```
git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git
```

Then I selected the branch I want:

```
git checkout PHP-7.3
```

Then I ran:

```
./buildconf
```

What is the next step?

I need the following packages:

php7.3
  libapache2-mod-php7.3
  php7.3-mysql
  mysql-server

I didn't search for a PPA, because I wanted to do it on my own in order to learn by doing it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Install dependencies.

   Ubuntu 16.04:

   ```
   sudo apt install autoconf automake bison build-essential curl flex \
     libtool libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev libreadline7 \
     libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libzip-dev libzip4 nginx openssl \
     pkg-config re2c sqlite3 zlib1g-dev libonig2 libonig-dev
   ```

   Ubuntu 18.04:

   ```
   sudo apt install autoconf automake bison build-essential curl flex \
     libtool libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev libreadline7 \
     libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libzip-dev libzip4 nginx openssl \
     pkg-config re2c sqlite3 zlib1g-dev libonig4 libonig-dev
   ```

   Ubuntu 20.04:

   ```
   sudo apt install autoconf automake bison build-essential curl flex \
     libtool libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev libreadline8 \
     libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libzip-dev libzip5 nginx openssl \
     pkg-config re2c sqlite3 zlib1g-dev libonig5 libonig-dev
   ```

   Ubuntu 22.04-23.04:

   ```
   sudo apt install autoconf automake bison build-essential curl flex \
     libtool libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev libreadline8 \
     libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libzip-dev libzip4 nginx openssl \
     pkg-config re2c sqlite3 zlib1g-dev libonig5 libonig-dev
   ```

   So you don't overwrite any existing PHP installs on your system, install PHP in your home directory. Create a directory for the PHP binaries.

   ```
    mkdir -p ~/bin/php7-latest/
   ```
2. Download the PHP 7.3 from [GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-7.3), decompress it, then change directories using `cd` to the new directory. You can also download other versions of PHP from the GitHub by changing https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-7.3 to https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-X.X. You can also download PHP 7.3 from [php.net/downloads.php](http://php.net/downloads.php) and the installation instructions are exactly the same. Ordinarily this would be the preferred way of downloading PHP 7.3, but I'm using PHP 7.3 from https://github.com/php/ in this answer instead in order to match the PHP 7.3 archive that is asked about in the question.
3. Configure PHP. Remove any options you don't need (like MySQL or Postgres (--with-pdo-pgsql))

   ```
    ./configure --prefix=$HOME/bin/php-latest \
        --enable-mysqlnd \
        --with-pdo-mysql \
        --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
        --with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/bin/pg_config \
        --enable-bcmath \
        --enable-fpm \
        --with-fpm-user=www-data \
        --with-fpm-group=www-data \
        --enable-mbstring \
        --enable-phpdbg \
        --enable-shmop \
        --enable-sockets \
        --enable-sysvmsg \
        --enable-sysvsem \
        --enable-sysvshm \
        --enable-zip \
        --with-libzip=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
        --with-zlib \
        --with-curl \
        --with-pear \
        --with-openssl \
        --enable-pcntl \
        --with-readline
   ```

   Probably you won't need to remove any of the options except for `--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/bin/pg_config` if PostgreSQL isn't installed. If you don't remove an option that is specific to a package that isn't installed, then this command will return an error message that tells you what option must be removed so that the command will run successfully.
4. Compile the binaries:

   ```
   make # wait until make is finished
   ```

   When make is finished you will see the following message:

   ```
   Build complete.
   Don't forget to run 'make test'.
   ```

   Warning: `make test` takes a long time to finish, so don't run it when the computer is busy.

   ```
   make install
   ```
5. Copy the PHP.ini file to the install directory

   ```
   cp php.ini-development ~/bin/php-latest/lib/
   ```
6. Rename two files.

   ```
   cd ~/bin/php-latest/etc/  
   mv php-fpm.conf.default php-fpm.conf
   mv php-fpm.d/www.conf.default php-fpm.d/www.conf
   ```
7. Create symbolic links for your for your binary file.

   ```
   cd ~/bin
   ln -s php-latest/bin/php php
   ln -s php-latest/bin/php-cgi php-cgi
   ln -s php-latest/bin/php-config php-config
   ln -s php-latest/bin/phpize phpize
   ln -s php-latest/bin/phar.phar phar
   ln -s php-latest/bin/pear pear
   ln -s php-latest/bin/phpdbg phpdbg
   ln -s php-latest/sbin/php-fpm php-fpm
   ```
8. Link your local PHP to the php command. You will need to logout then log back in for php to switch to the local version instead of the installed version from the default Ubuntu repositories.

   ```
   # add this to .bashrc
   if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
     PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
   fi
   ```
9. Start PHP-FPM

   ```
   sudo ~/bin/php-latest/sbin/php-fpm
   ```

   If you run the above command as normal user without sudo, it will show the following notices:

   ```
   NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root.    
   NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root.
   ```

<sub>**Source:** The Install file in php-src-master directory from https://github.com/php/php-src.git contains a link to https://php.net/install from which source these instructions were revised. In addition to several small revisions I added information about how to install PHP 7.3 locally in your home directory without requiring root permissions.</sub>

Comment: I haven't had to deploy PHP for years so I was wondering if nginx is required when one is planning on using apache such as OP listed. It is included in your apt install list

Comment: Documentation is at [PHP: Debian GNU/Linux installation notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.debian.php) Search for *Compiling PHP on Ubuntu boxes*. This is a user contributed note, and I don't think that nginx is required.

Comment: The folder `=$HOME/bin/php-latest` does not exist after executing the configure & make & make install commands

Comment: @Black The `$HOME/bin/php-latest` folder was created automatically when I followed the steps in my answer a few minutes ago in Ubuntu 20.04. When following these steps I found out that some of the dependencies from Ubuntu 16.04 have been updated to more recent versions, so I edited my answer by updating it with additional information for users who are using Ubuntu 20.04.