# Should I add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2 when I add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php, as advised?

Tags: apt, 18.04, apache2, ppa, php7

I am upgrading an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server to PHP 7.4 because PHP 7.2 is no longer supported.

Other public questions have directed me to add `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`, such as [How to update/upgrade PHP 7.2 to latest version safely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146109/how-to-update-upgrade-php-7-2-to-latest-version-safely)

When I run `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`, the following information is displayed to me (quoting the relevant part for purposes of this question):

> CAVEATS:
>
> 1. If you are using php-gearman, you need to add ppa:ondrej/pkg-gearman
> 2. If you are using apache2, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/apache2
> 3. If you are using nginx, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline
>       or ppa:ondrej/nginx

Should I `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2` as well, if I am running apache2 on this server?

Comment: Hello. That is what the update told you to do.

Comment: I'm asking because [How to update/upgrade PHP 7.2 to latest version safely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146109/how-to-update-upgrade-php-7-2-to-latest-version-safely) says nothing about `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2` or `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline` or `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/nginx`.

Comment: Are you running nginx?

Comment: No, I'm running apache2. I am just referring to the CAVEATS that were displayed when I initially executed `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`, and I wanted to make reference to each of the web server-related caveats.

Comment: FYI, I don't know anything about gearman, and I don't believe it's part of any of my server installations.

Comment: Well if not running nginx why would you add the ppa for them?

Comment: I don't want to debate my question, and I'm sorry if it seems like that's what I'm doing.

If `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2` is necessary because otherwise the PHP 7.4 software won't be accessible from the running Apache 2 instance, that's what I was hoping would be discussed in an answer to my question.

As written, the CAVEAT doesn't explain why I am advised to add the apache 2 ppa.

Comment: Just being clear I would do the 2 ppa as it suggests you should.

Comment: I used to use the ondrej ppa for apache for years and had no problems. I never used php though.

Answer (score 6):

My interpretation of your question is that you would like to know *why* you're being advised to install `ppa:ondrej/apache2` over the default Ubuntu Apache2 package. The most authoritative answer I could find to this question is [from the PPA author](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1110):

**Q**

> In the main PHP PPA it is recommended that:
>
> > If you are using apache2, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/apache2
>
> However, there are no arguments as to why this is recommended, what
> benefits this apache build will have and what risks systems might be
> exposed to by doing so...

**A**

> apache2 has all the fancy stuff like modern crypto, HTTP/2.0 and
> TLS/3.
>
> For the rest, you need to do your own research (I provide couple of
> updated modules that has been requested) and maybe submit a patch for
> the description if you want to see it improved.

In [another GitHub issue](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1214#issuecomment-519916223), the author gives a similar answer:

**Q**

> On a related topic: I see that you recommend using the ondrej/apache2
> source for Apache as well ("If you are using apache2, you are advised
> to add ppa:ondrej/apache2"). Can you give me an idea of the risks of
> not using ondrej/apache2 if I'm using ondrej/php?

**A**

> The apache2 from PPA is up-to-date, has better HTTP/2 support, has
> TLS1.3 support. There are no risk per se.

The reasons given should not apply to Apache2 from the Ubuntu 18.04 repos; the latest release, `2.4.29`, [supports TLS 1.3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571082/123820), and HTTP/2 should just work.

It would be helpful if the PPA maintainer updated [the FAQ page](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) to this effect, and perhaps elaborated a bit on when this advisory is actually applicable.