# Install PHP 7.3 or 7.4 without PPA Ubuntu16.04

Tags: package-management, mysql, php, dependencies

I'm wondering if there's a way to download php7.3 or 7.4 without using a ppa? I haven't been able to find a good alternative I tried out `apt install lamp-server^` but that wasn't sufficient enough and when downloading some files I got unmet dependencie error:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not goiing to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution.)`

I did all the trouble shooting `apt -f install` didn't work and I did other methods but the only fix was to uninstall the packages from `lamp-sever^`.

Let me know your suggestions and ideas, I'm looking for a NON-PPA solution.

~ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build PHP 7.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102910/how-to-build-php-7-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can't do it safely, sorry.**

Ubuntu and it's many applications are bound together in a *snapshot release* model pioneered by Debian. In this model, applications and the OS are released together and use the same versions of shared libraries. In the Ubuntu universe of mostly volunteer-made and volunteer-supported software, this method greatly limits the amount of testing and support that needs to be done, and limits the number of corner cases.

However, this is quite unlike the Windows *OS-as-black-box model*, where any version of software can run on any version of the OS, and the two are not tightly coupled. Of course, you *pay* for that flexibility provided by commercial software providers.

The Bottom Line: If you want newer software in Ubuntu without using non-Ubuntu sources, then you must run a newer release of Ubuntu. PHP 7.4, for example, is available in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.