# install php 7.1 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php7, 20.04

I have recently install ubuntu 20.04 - focal fossal.

I tried to add ondrej PPA. But it is not working.

I only could install php7.4 by apt get.

Please help.

Comment: Do you need specifically 7.1? The PHP version in Ubuntu 20.04 is 7.4, and PPAs may take a little while to make 20.04 versions available. PHP 7.1 is end-of-life and was only supperted until 1 December 2019. When I've needed different specific versions I've found it easier to use Docker.

Comment: @Kurankat has the correct comment/answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build PHP 7.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102910/how-to-build-php-7-3) PHP 7.2 is end of life, but you can still download PHP 7.2 from https://www.php.net/downloads.php and then follow the instructions in the accepted answer to install it alongside PHP 7.4 that was installed by apt.

Comment: PHP 7.1 is end of life, not PHP 7.2.

Comment: This wasn't answered anywhere. Because the issue is not about installing php in general but  certain php packages of a certain php  version on Ubuntu 20.04. Ubuntu doesn't provide packages bellow 7.4. But some packages aren't available yet for 7.4. But you can still use older php versions of some php packages (in my case php7.3-recode). You could have just comment your stuff instead of closing the question!!

Comment: Here is a similar open question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231491/ubuntu-20-04-cant-install-older-php-versions

Comment: One more related question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231381/unable-to-install-php-7-3-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: My question was not answered. The links provided not worked!