# Ubuntu 20.04 - Can't Install Older PHP Versions

Tags: apt, php, ppa, 20.04, php7

I decided to install Ubuntu 20.04 and give it a go. I am loving it so far, but I have run into an issue that may prevent me from using it.

The default repositories have PHP 7.4, which is awesome, but I need 7.2 or 7.3 for the project I spend 90% of my time working on.

I've used the ondrej/php PPA in the past (mostly to get newer PHP versions than were available on older releases) but it does not seem to be working on this release. Am I missing something, or does anyone here know how to get it working?

Adding the PPA seems to be successful, but even after updating the repos I cannot install or even view older PHP versions. After adding the repository there are no new entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but I am not sure if that is where PPA's are even added.

I appreciate any and all help I can get. Thank you.

Comment: having the same issue upgraded to 20.04 and im unable to install php7.1. have you found a solution?